# Why do backslashes need to be escaped in JPA native queries?

Tags: jpa, escaping, openjpa, nativequery

In JPA, when executing a native query, I have to escape backslash characters to double backslash. E.g. when having a where clause like

```
UPPER(app.NAME) like UPPER(?) escape '\'
```

then I need to create a string which contains:

```
UPPER(app.NAME) like UPPER(?) escape '\\'
```

Then I run a native query using openJPA 2.2.2:

```
final EntityManager entityManager = EntityManagerFinder.getEntityManager();
final Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, Response.class);
```

The SQL statement is read from XML file, hence Java escaping is not done here. Furthermore I verified during debugging that the String in Java is really the same as in the XML file.

Why is JPA expecting double backslash for native queries? Is this a bug in openJPA?

Comment: maybe the backslash escape is for the JDBC driver? because some do need that (such as MySQL).

Answer (score 2):

@Neil: It was a good hint that it could be DB specific, not JPA specific.
Using Oracle 11gR2, I found: [Special characters in Oracle Text Queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cqspcl.htm)

"To escape the backslash escape character, use \."

However, I do not understand why I need to escape backslash when I use JPA, but in PL/SQL Developer, I MUST NOT escape. If I escape backslash in PL/SQL Developer, I get an error message.

Furthermore the trace log of openJPA shows the SQL, which was submitted with '\' as '\', which is quite confusing.

Regarding JDBC:
The [Oracle JDBC documentation / LIKE Escape Characters](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxref.htm#JJDBC28921) mentions:

"If you want to use the backslash character () as an escape character, then you must enter it twice, that is, \. For example:"

```
ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT empno FROM emp
            WHERE ename LIKE '\\_%' {escape '\\'}");
```

which is a simple Java escape, and Java-internal results in a single backslash character.

I also must escape in regular expressions, not only in LIKE:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
  listagg(h.node_id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY h.node_id),
  '([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1') as node_ids
```

So I'm still confused as it's not escaped neither in the JPA trace log nor when executing it in PL/SQL developer. The JPA trace should be the SQL which is sent to the DB driver.